# How to make iPhone screen dim

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a refresh button on my iphone screen that refreshes a table in the current view.

The screen refresh beautifully, but is there a way I can make the screen dim and then lighten again after the table has refreshed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could place a non-opaque view with a black background over the view you wish to dim. This would have an alpha value of 0 by default and thus be transparent. You could then use a UIView animation to set the black views alpha from 0 to 0.5 (say) and then back.

***Note:*** The code below has not been tested but I have used similar to achieve the same effect.

```
    ...
    dimView.alpha = 0.0f;
    [UIView beginAnimations@"fade" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    dimView.alpha = 0.5f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    ...
}

- (void) animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    dimView.alpha = 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: I removed two lines of the code above to make it work that way I needed. Here is the final result: 
<p>
<pre><code> 
self.tableView.alpha = 0.0f; 
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fade" context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f]; 
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; 
self.tableView.alpha = 1.0f; [UIView commitAnimations]; 
</code> 
</pre>

Comment: Would the device draw less power when the display is dimmed? And by what extent, lets say I keep the display on for 20 minutes, how much battery time would be gained if any.

Comment: I found a wired article, that describes screen brightness for an iPhone4, indicating quite a bit of power saving. I am wondering if newer diplay types are the same, OLED vs the other technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Could you load a black, 50% alpha view over the top, possibly fade in?